# Representing Heatsinks on board layout

Tags: pcb-design, heatsink, cad

When using CAD software to draw board layouts, is there any convention on how to represent heatsinks attached to, say, some power transistors? I want to make sure they don't interfere with one another, and representing them on the board layout makes it easier to spot problems when I am moving stuff around.

It seems to me the alternatives are:

- represent heatsinks as a separate component
- modify the transistor's footprint so that it includes the heatsink
- just draw the heatsinks on some separate layer that's normally off, and turn it on when checking for interferences

So far, I am very partial to the first option, and have been making heatsink components on Eagle and adding them right next to the transistors:

[image: custom heatsink footprint on Eagle]

However, I've never seen anyone do it like this. Is this a bad idea? Is there any sort of convention on that?

Comment: What program are you using? In Altium we can just add a 3D body to the design.

Answer (score 2):

It is called the keepout layer. I would include it in the transistor footprint for positional accuracy but it might be useful to have it separate for a PCB assembler so they know they have two components there on the BOM and pick and place list.